# Append div based on dragend mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to append div based on `dragend` event coordinates. This is what I have tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;
            $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                mouseX = e.pageX;
                mouseY = e.pageY;
            });
            var i =1;
            $(".ic_table").on("dragend", function (e, ui)
            {
                console.log(mouseX + " " + mouseY);
                var editName = "Edit Name";
                $('#datamodelArea').append('<div id="divDT' + i++ + '" class="dataModelTable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle style="left:' + mouseX + 'px' + '; top:' + mouseY + 'px' + ';"><div class="dataTableName">' + editName + '</div><div class="widget"><div class="widget-head"> <a href="#" id="toggle1" class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-1x attributes"><i></i></a> Attributes <div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"></div></div></div><div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"><ul></ul></div></div>');
                $('.form-control').val('');
            });
        });
```

Html:

```
<body>
        <div id="datamodelArea"></div>
        <button class="ic_table" draggable="true">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Its appending only to `top:0px` and `left:0px` even though the mouse coordinates are different on dragend

Answer (score 0):

Set your position properties explicitly to relative for the container and absolute for the dropped.